# Disable tap on current Tab (UITabBarController) iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

Currently, Tapping on the same Tab (in which user is working), The App moves to the very first page of that Tab.

I want to disable the tap event on the Tab in which user is working currently.

Any Hint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You tried `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` delegate method? I hope that should help you.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    id currentViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    return (viewController != currentViewController);
}
```

If all the view controllers of the tab bar controller are `UINavigationControllers`, you should do it like this.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    id nextVC = [(UINavigationController *)viewController topViewController];
    id currentVC = [(UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController topViewController];
    return (nextVC != currentVC);
}
```

For Swift 4 the delegate method looks like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
}
```

Comment: I found that method, but what code must go into it..., that I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, All VCs are `UINavigationControllers`. Any specific reason to typecast for `(UINavigationController *)` or just for the sake of good programming practices. It works without that, too.

Answer (score 0):

use like below it will work

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController])
            return  NO;   
        else
            return YES;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the else part of the if-else statement.  If it returns NO, it can't return YES.